# Retrace for DexGuard

Tags: android, obfuscation, deobfuscation, dexguard

I use [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard) for obfuscation. I have the stack trace from crash log and the mapping file. When I run `retrace.bat`, giving it the stack trace and the mapping file, the output is still in the obfuscated format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using **ProGuard**'s retrace.bat? It cannot deobfuscate stack traces that were obfuscated with DexGuard. Solution is to use **DexGuard**'s retrace tool instead:

> java -jar /var/DexGuard/lib/retrace.jar -verbose mapping.txt trace.txt

DexGuard's is backwards compatible, i.e., it can also retrace ProGuard obfuscated stack traces.

Comment: I totally did this too

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if DexGuard has obfuscated using non-ASCII characters, and these characters get mangled when you export the log from the device. One (crude) way of working around this is to use `adb logcat -B` to export the log in binary.